# Use of AM/PM in time

Tags: traducción, tiempo

Aside from using 'military time' (19:00 for 7:00 PM), is there another approach to delineate between AM/PM time in Spanish?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

En español se usan las las abreviaturas *a. m.* (del latín *ante merídiem* "antes del mediodía") y *p. m.* (del latín *post merídiem* "después del mediodía"). Estas abreviaturas deben escribirse en minúsculas y con la puntuación indicada. Para las doce de la mañana (o del mediodía) se utiliza *m.* (del latín *meridies* "mediodía"). Así, por ejemplo:

> La entrada es a las 7.30 a. m. (la entrada es a las siete y media de la mañana).
>
> El servicio se realizará a las 5 p. m. (el servicio se realizará a las cinco de la tarde).
>
> La clase es a las 12 m. (la clase es a las doce del mediodía).

Para más información sobre la hora en español, ver [hora](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=hora2) en el *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas*.

---

In Spanish, the abbreviations *a. m.* (from the Latin *ante meridiem* "antes del mediodía") and *p. m.* (from the Latin *post meridiem* "después del mediodía") are used. These abbreviations are written in lower case and using the indicated punctuation. For noon it is custumary to use *m.* (from the Latin *meridies* "mediodía"). For example:

> La entrada es a las 7.30 a. m. (la entrada es a las siete y media de la mañana).
>
> El servicio se realizará a las 5 p. m. (el servicio se realizará a las cinco de la tarde).
>
> La clase es a las 12 m. (la clase es a las doce del mediodía).

For more information on the hour in Spanish, see [hora](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=hora2) in *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas*.

Comment: +1 buena respuesta :-D

Comment: Cabe hacer mención de que en español estas abreviaturas deben escribirse espaciadas, a diferencia de la práctica ortotipográfica anglosajona; así: «a. m.» (español) vs. “a.m.” (inglés).

Comment: Gracias por ejemplos

Answer (score 7):

In speech in Mexico I only ever noticed

- *de la mañana* for *a. m.*
- *de la tarde* for *p. m.*

In English pronouncing the abbreviations is just as common in speech as in writing but I'm sure I never heard anyone pronounce them in spoken Spanish though it's clear from the other answers here that they are normal in written Spanish.

Comment: I definitely endorse this answer. "AM" and "PM" feel quite pedantic in speech.

Comment: Agreed.  Example: *Vamos a salir a las 10 de la mañana, y llegaremos allá a las 5 de la tarde.  La ceremonia empieza a las 8 de la noche.*

Comment: That made it more easy. I like this one more.

Answer (score 3):

You use AM / PM in Spanish the same way you use AM / PM in English. In fact they mean the same in both languages:

> AM =  Ante Meridiem = Before noon = Antes del mediodía
>
> PM =  Post Meridiem = Past noon   = Después del mediodía

Answer (score -3):

In Spanish we have three major designations and one general designation in regards to expressing time. Gonzalo, A.M. is NOT Spanish, it is Latin for Ante.  Sometimes it is easier to ask for gimeridio and post meridio, those two are more explicit and NOT abbreviated in becomes conversational Spanish. In the case of which a time may be 10 AM or 10 PM corresponding  and  . The general usage is when is  and is usually for a situation where it is too late in the day for the activity though not particularity all that late in regards to your plans and so you would say  meaning in the day. This instance is reserved for when you cannot or do not want to commit to a particular time frame and at the same time shifts the responsibility to your respondent to determine an appropriate time frame as well. Some would have to ask forgiveness; where is the Chrarisma when demanding?

Comment: Can you please improve the quality of your answer? There are some grammatical and spelling errors that make some passages of your answer rather unintelligible.